# How can I create multiple plots from same dataset in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

Let me first share a dummy data, from which I want to prepare ggplot graphs.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
sample_size <- 1200
dates <- sample(seq(1,31),sample_size,replace = TRUE)
Monthss <- sample(seq(1,12),sample_size,replace = TRUE)
hrs <- sample(seq(1,23),sample_size,replace = TRUE)
minutes <- sample(seq(1,59),sample_size,replace = TRUE)
date_time_vector <- paste0(dates,"-",Monthss,"-",2022," ",hrs,":",minutes) |> lubridate::parse_date_time("dmy HM")
Conversion <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),sample_size, prob = c(0.25,0.75), replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(Date = date_time_vector, Conversion_Status = Conversion)
df <- df |> mutate(Leads = round(runif(sample_size, min = 0,max = 10),digits = 0))
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
```

The code above gives me a data.frame with columns Date, Leads and Conversion_Status. I want to prepare Monthly column chart of total leads per day. (For example, daily leads in January, daily leads in February, etc.) So, basically, I will need to split the data on the basis of Month, and prepare one chart for each month. How can I prepare such charts?

I have tried following way:

```
bar_function <- function(df, col1, col2, title) {
  df %>% 
    ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = {{col1}}, y = {{col2}})) +
    ggplot2::geom_col(fill = "steelblue") +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+coord_flip() +
    ggplot2::labs(title = title)
}
mycharts <- df |> dplyr::nest_by(Month) |> dplyr::mutate(plot = bar_function(df,Date,Leads,"Daily Leads by Month"))
```

But it is giving me errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can split according to month(year) and plot that.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1)
sample_size <- 1200
dates <- sample(seq(1,31),sample_size,replace = TRUE)
Monthss <- sample(seq(1,12),sample_size,replace = TRUE)
hrs <- sample(seq(1,23),sample_size,replace = TRUE)
minutes <- sample(seq(1,59),sample_size,replace = TRUE)
date_time_vector <- paste0(dates,"-",Monthss,"-",2022," ",hrs,":",minutes) |> lubridate::parse_date_time("dmy HM")
Conversion <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),sample_size, prob = c(0.25,0.75), replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(Date = date_time_vector, Conversion_Status = Conversion)
df$Leads <- round(runif(sample_size, min = 0,max = 10),digits = 0)
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]

df$month_year <- strftime(df$Date, format = "%m-%Y")

df.split <- split(df, f = df$month_year)
out <- vector("list", length(df.split))
names(out) <- names(df.split)

for (i in seq_along(df.split)) {
  out[[i]] <- ggplot(data = df.split[[i]], mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Leads)) +
    geom_col(fill = "steelblue") +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title = "Daily leads by month")
}
```

To plot you can just print e.g. `out[[1]]`.

If you want to change the desired columns dynamically, you can use `aes_string` for mapping. This can naturally be wrapped into `sapply` and there are probably other ways of approaching the problem. The for loop is pretty agnostic and I find that it's readable even by people who do not dabble in R (compared to say `sapply`).

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code. First, your dataset has no `Month` column, i.e. you have to add it for which I use `lubridate::month`. Second, you are passing the dataset `df` to your bar function instead of the splitted `data` column from your nested df. Third, in the `mutate` step you have to wrap the result in `list()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

mycharts <- df |>
  nest_by(Month = lubridate::month(Date)) |>
  mutate(plot = list(bar_function(data, Date, Leads, "Daily Leads by Month")))

mycharts$plot[[1]]
```

[image]

```r
mycharts$plot[[5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer. I used following code:

```
lapply(split(df, df$Month), 
                 function(x) 
                   ggplot(x, aes(x=Date, y=Leads)) +
                   geom_col(fill = "steelblue") + coord_flip()+
                   ggtitle(x$Month[1]))
```

Thank you all for your support.